# Why won't exec define my variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.execute()
    def execute(self):
        exec('self.myVar = 1') in MyClass()
```

When I try to call

```
exec('self.myVar = 1') in MyClass()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: exec: arg 2 must be a dictionary or None
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MyClass()` is not a dictionary (used to represent global, local namespaces). `self` is a local name anyway. What do you want to do here? What is the intent of the code?

Comment: This is *not* Python 3, by the way. That `exec` syntax went away in Python 3 (it's now `exec(obj, globals, locals)`). This is definitely Python 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation

> If only the first expression after `in` is specified, it should be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables. If two expressions are given, both must be dictionaries and they are used for the global and local variables, respectively.

So basically, the expressions after `in` are supposed to be `globals()` and `locals()` with any additional keys you want to be in scope during the `exec` statement. Essentially, you use `in` to define an execution scope for `exec`, as in *execute this statement in these namespaces*.

Semantically, it's equivalent to `eval(statement, globals, locals)`

In your case, you can just leave out the `in MyClass()` clause completely.

Note that `eval`/`exec` leave you vulnerable to arbitrary code execution if you're not the one constructing the statement string (I assume your code example is a toy sample meant to illustrate your problem), so keep that in mind.

Comment: to add: `exec` is at the right most position (the most powerful) on [Levels of Magic from `macropy` package](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#levels-of-magic) after metaclasses, macros in Python. Less powerful capabilities are usually preferable (less damage if something goes wrong. The more power the more responsibility).